# Calculate $z^m + z^{-m},$ if $z^1 + z^{-1} = 2 \cos\phi$

Tags: complex-numbers

I was given a task to calculate $z^m + z^{-m},$ if $z^1 + z^{-1} = 2  \cos\phi$. I found a similar question, but there were no explanations, so I did not understand the solutions. Please clarify how can I solve this.

I tried multiple approaches but it leads nowhere.

Comment: Hello welcome to MSE! What have you tried to solve the problem? Edit your attempts into your post.

Comment: The $z+z^{-1}=2\cos\theta$ equation can be solved.

Comment: $z + z^{-1} = 2\cos(\theta) \implies z^2 - 2z\cos(\theta) + 1 = 0.$  Applying the quadratic formula you have that $$z = \frac{1}{2} \left[2\cos(\theta) \pm \sqrt{4\cos^2(\theta) - 4}~\right] = \cos(\theta) \pm \left[i ~\sqrt{\sin^2(\theta)}~\right].$$  Here, the two possible roots represent interchanging $z$ and $z^{-1}.$ Note also that $\sqrt{\sin^2(\theta)} = |\sin(\theta)|.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the question we obtain $|z + 1/z| = |2\cos\phi| \le 2$, which yields $z$ is complex. Any complex number can be written as $z = r(\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)$ for some $r >0$. Note that $$z + 1/z = r (\cos\phi + i \sin \phi) + \frac{1}{r(\cos\phi + i \sin\phi)} = r(\cos \phi + i \sin \phi) + 1/r (\cos \phi - i \sin \phi) $$
$$ = (r + 1/r) \cos \phi + i \sin \phi (r - 1/r) = 2\cos\phi $$
Comparing the imaginary parts, we obtain $r = 1$ ($r = - 1$ is not permitted). Hence $z = (\cos \phi + i \sin \phi)$ and finally by DeMoivre we have
$$ z^m + \frac{1}{z^m} = (\cos m\phi + i \sin m \phi) + (\cos m\phi-i\sin m \phi) = 2 \cos m \phi $$

Comment: Great answer! I just have 2 questions. 1) Why is $|z + 1/z| = |2\cos\phi| \le 2$ ?

Comment: 2) Why is $\frac{1}{cosx+sinx} = cosx−sinx$

Comment: @RasadevX Note that $-1 \le \cos \phi \le 1$, thus $|\cos\phi|\le 1$. The rest follows. For the next question, at first, it's either a typing mistake or a conceptual mistake in understanding the solution. *I did not say $\frac{1}{\cos x + \sin x} = \cos x - \sin x$*, what I said was: $$ \frac{1}{\cos x + i \sin x} = \cos x - i \sin x$$ It's fairly easy to see. $$ \frac{1}{\cos x + i \sin x} = \frac{\cos x - i \sin x}{(\cos^2 x + \sin^2 x)} = \cos x - i \sin x $$